# How do I return anything from a function after changing a state variable in solidity?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

```
function setName(string memory _name) public returns(string memory){
name = _name;
return "Name was set";
}
```

I want to return a confirmation message after the string was set but whenever I try to deploy, its working fine and even the name is being set but it's not returning the string "Name was set".
Can anyone help me out with this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

State changing functions don't exactly *return* something you can use in the common sense outside your smart contract, such as in testing.

For that purpose, we use [Events](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/contracts.html#events) to log what happened, and then query the logs or simply call the getter function after you are done executing your setter function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually state changing functions **can** return values. **But**, that values can be read by another Smart Contracts, that made a transaction. In other words, return values in state changing functions can not be read by EOM accounts.